# Grails form submit works only for some fields

Tags: forms, grails

Grails 3.1.6, and a form build with the grails-field-plugin. Only part of the field set, is updated when trying to update. The user controller is scaffolded. In this scenario only the fields "birthday" and "country" react to the update. The other fields are totally ignored. If we remove these two fields from the update form, the remaining fields react regularly to the update request.

Here the part of the view referring the form:

```
<g:form resource="${this.user}" method="PUT">
    <g:hiddenField name="version" value="${this.user?.version}"/>
    <fieldset class="form">
        <f:with bean="user">
            <f:field property="firstName">
                <g:textField name="firstName" value="${user?.firstName}"/>
            </f:field>
            <f:field property="lastName">
                <g:textField name="lastName" value="${user?.lastName}"/>
            </f:field>
            <f:field property="birthday">
                <g:datePicker name="birthday" precision="day" value="${user?.birthday}"
                              years="${2016..1900}" default="${user?.birthday}"/>
            </f:field>
            <f:field property="country">
                <g:countrySelect name="country" value="${user?.country}"
                                 noSelection="['': '-Choose your country-']"
                                 default="${user?.country}"/>
            </f:field>
            <f:field property="address">
                <g:textField name="address" value="${user?.address}"/>
            </f:field>
        </f:with>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <input class="save" type="submit"
               value="${message(code: 'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}"/>
    </fieldset>
</g:form>
```

Here the user domain class

```
class User {
String firstName
String lastName
String email
String password
Date birthday
String country
String address
static constraints = {
    firstName blank: false
    lastName blank: false
    email email: true, blank: false
    password blank: false, size: 5..15, matches: /[\S]+/
    birthday max: new Date()
    country nullable: true
    address nullable: true
}}
```

Any idea on why this happens?!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
<f:field property="firstName"/>
```

Instead of

```
<f:field property="firstName">
     <g:textField name="firstName" value="${user?.firstName}"/>
</f:field>
```

Although, I haven't used this plugin before. Looking at the usage https://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/guide/usage.html

I don't think the inner tag is needed

Comment: Thank for the answer. Solved, the inner tag is NOT a problem itsef. What matters is that the property name should be the same in the outer and the inner tag, otherwise the whole field set breaks. In the .gsp file I've posted here,in  the "country" and the "birthday" fields both tags refers to the same property name. So is OK like this, but in the editor I'm testing, the inner tag of "country" refers to "user.country" property while the outer refers to "country" property. This causes the wrong behavior I mentioned.